# Swift Regex does not detect groups properly?

Tags: swift, regex

This is my regex: `((?<days>\d+)\s*Tag[e]?\s*)?((?<hours>\d+)\s*[Ss]td\.\s*)?((?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in\s*)?`

This is the code that uses the regex:

```
if let content = element.text {
    let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "((?<days>\\d+)\\s*Tag[e]?\\s*)?((?<hours>\\d+)\\s*[Ss]td\\.\\s*)?((?<minutes>\\d+)\\s*[Mm]in\\s*)?")
    let matches = regex!.matches(in: content, range: NSRange(content.startIndex..., in: content))
    
    var valueSet = false;
    
    if let match = matches.first {
        let daysRange = match.range(withName: "days")
        if let swiftDaysRange = Range(daysRange, in: content) {
            let days = Int(content[swiftDaysRange].replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")) ?? 0
            validTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: Date())!
            valueSet = true
        }
        
        let hoursRange = match.range(withName: "hours")
        if let swiftHoursRange = Range(hoursRange, in: content) {
            let hours = Int(content[swiftHoursRange].replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")) ?? 0
            if valueSet {
                validTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hours, to: validTo)!
            } else {
                validTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hours, to: Date())!
            }
            
            valueSet = true
        }
        
        let minutesRange = match.range(withName: "minutes")
        if let swiftMinutesRange = Range(minutesRange, in: content) {
            let minutes = Int(content[swiftMinutesRange].replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")) ?? 0
            if valueSet {
                validTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: validTo)!
            } else {
                validTo = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: Date())!
            }
            
            valueSet = true
        }
    }
}
```

So far, the regex does match. However it won't detect the groups until I change my regex to this one (which will not work in production because all parts are optional): `(?<days>\d+)\s*Tag[e]?\s*(?<hours>\d+)\s*[Ss]td\.\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in\s*`

My question is now, what did I miss to tell Swift also search for groups inside this optional wrappings in my regex? I expected that Swift would also work with the first version without such problems. There is also no information in Apple's documentation about this special kind of problem (or I just don't know what I have to look for).

Comment: Can you please add the string that you are searching at? What is the value of `content`?

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't know how this helps because `matches.first` is **not** `nil` (it's just not able to find the groups). Valid content can be this for example: "verbleibend für 20 Tage 21 Std." or "verbleibend für 20 Tage 21 Std. 10 Min" or "verbleibend für 1 Tag".

Comment: @LeoDabus this will make most cases invalid. The regex is correct for sure. Removing the `?` at the end, will make minutes a must - that's a nogo.

Comment: If the order of the units is fixed, you may try `(?<days>\d+)\s*Tage?\s*(?:(?<hours>\d+)\s*[Ss]td\.(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in)?)?`, see https://regex101.com/r/OWP5ha/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and why is swift capable of handling this and not the other version? I tested it before, see: https://regex101.com/r/OR5vAA/1 (I would prefer to understand why Swift does not work with the other version which runs fine on Regex101, PHP and C# - would help me understand it and learn from it)

Comment: What do you mean by "capable of handling this and not the other version"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex in my code is also a valid regex for this. It works in Regex101, PHP and C# without any problems. Why does it not work in Swift while the version you created work? Only thing you changed is where the optional mark is set and adding the `?:` in.

Comment: Swift uses [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) style regex, maybe it's not the same as Regex101, php or C#?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is true ICU is different, but the pattern will work the same across these engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the order of time units is fixed, I suggest using

```
(?<days>\d+)\s*Tage?(?:\s*(?<hours>\d+)\s*[Ss]td\.(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in)?)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OWP5ha/2). Look how it matches:

- `(?<days>\d+)\s*Tage?` - obligatory part:

  - `(?<days>\d+)` - Group "days": one or more digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `Tage?` - `Tag` and then an optional `e`
- `(?:\s*(?<hours>\d+)\s*[Ss]td\.(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in)?)?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?<hours>\d+)` - Group "hours": 1 or more digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `[Ss]td\.` - `Std.` or `std.`
  - `(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*[Mm]in)?` - an optional sequence of patterns:

    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `(?<minutes>\d+)` - Group "minutes": 1+ digits
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `[Mm]in` - `Min` or `min`